# Masking pandas dataframe of dates using another dataframe of events

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": pd.date_range(start="2012-03-01", end="2012-03-05"),
                       "date+1": pd.date_range(start="2012-03-02", end="2012-03-06"),
                       "date+2": pd.date_range(start="2012-03-03", end="2012-03-07")})
```

I also have another dataframe representing events with start date and end date as follows.

```
event = pd.DataFrame({"event": ["A", "B"],
                      "start": ["2012-03-02", "2012-03-04"],
                      "end": ["2012-03-03", "2012-03-06"]})
event["start"] = pd.to_datetime(event["start"])
event["end"] = pd.to_datetime(event["end"])
```

I want to create a mask dataframe that return True if any date in df is between start date and end date of any event in the event dataframe.  The expected output should be

```
0,  1,  1
1,  1,  1
1,  1,  1
1,  1,  1
1,  1,  0
```

This expected output correspond to the df

```
2012-03-01,  2012-03-02,  2012-03-03
2012-03-02,  2012-03-03,  2012-03-04
2012-03-03,  2012-03-04,  2012-03-05
2012-03-04,  2012-03-05,  2012-03-06
2012-03-05,  2012-03-06,  2012-03-07
```

As you can see that only 2012-03-01 and 2012-03-07 are not between any event in the event dataframe.  Looping could be computational expensive.  May I have your suggestions how to minimize looping?

Comment: what about using ```from datetime import timedelta```? you can use like ```datetime('2012-03-01') + timedelta(days=1)``` This is just an example. so if you want, I will give complete code.

Comment: May I see the full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an [interval index](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.from_tuples.html) from `events`:

```
intervals = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples([*zip(event.start, event.end)], 
                                         closed = 'both')

IntervalIndex([[2012-03-02, 2012-03-03], [2012-03-04, 2012-03-06]],
              closed='both',
              dtype='interval[datetime64[ns]]')
```

Run [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) on `df`:

```
df.applymap(lambda df: intervals.contains(df).any()).astype(int)
 
   date  date+1  date+2
0     0       1       1
1     1       1       1
2     1       1       1
3     1       1       1
4     1       1       0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use cartesian join, then check that the date is between start and end of an interval, and aggregate:

```
# cartesian join
z = (df
    .stack().reset_index().assign(k=1)
    .merge(event.assign(k=1)))

# check if date between start and end
z['mask'] = z[0].between(z['start'], z['end'])

# aggregate
df_m = z.groupby(['level_0', 'level_1'])['mask'].max().unstack().astype(int)
df_m
```

Output:

```
level_1  date  date+1  date+2
level_0                      
0           0       1       1
1           1       1       1
2           1       1       1
3           1       1       1
4           1       1       0
```

P.S. Instead of that trick with assigning `k=1` to both frames before merging, if you're on a  newer version of `pandas` (1.2.0+), you can use `merge(how='cross')` directly